# How to make input disabled without loosing the ability to call ng-click on it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue to overcome. I have some radio buttons that are disabled when some conditions are satisfied, but normally when input is disabled by ng-disabled ng-click can't be call by clicking on that input. I need to display some alerts for user which will tell why particular option can't be selected and now I have a problem. Can someone help?

My html is something like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-disabled="my_conditions" ng-click="alertIfNeeded()">
```

Comment: I am looking for the best way to make this thing work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like click event won't fire on a `ng-disabled` `<button> / <input>` element but it will on an `<a>` element, if that works for your case. Check out this jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/q8r4e/

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="handleAnchorClick()">ANCHOR</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="handleButtonClick()">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Accordingly to your jsfiddle example: what I am looking for is the ability to call handleButtonClick when the button is disabled (or maybe make input disabled by something else than "disabled" attribute).

Answer (score 0):

set a status on scope to know if radios are disabled or not.

keep the last selected radio item in scope.

don't disable the radios.

on-click check if radio is disabled set the selected radio back to the previous one and alert the user, if its not disabled set the last selected radio to scope.